# Can I have some edges curved and other straight in Python igraph?

Tags: python, igraph, edges

I am trying to create the graph as shown in Python igraph and I am having trouble displaying some edge straight and others curved. Is this possible, the edge_curved function appears to only take one
argument.

[image]

[image]

```
# Construct the graph
g = ig.Graph(n=9,
    edges = [(6,7),(6,8),(6,3),(6,0),
             (7,8),(7,4),(7,3),
             (8,2),(8,5), 
             (3,4),(3,0),(4,1),(4,5), (5,2), (5,1),
             (0,1),(0,2), (1,2)])

#g.es["weight"] = [2, 1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 2]
g.es["label"]= ["a","b","c","d", "e", "g", "f", "e", "h", "j","k","m", "l", "o", "n", "p", "q", "r" ]
g.vs["name"] = ["G","H","X","D","E","F","A","B","C"]

print("Is simple ", g.is_simple())
print("Degree ", g.vs.degree())
print(g)

# Plot graph
g.es['width'] = 0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ig.plot(
    g,
    target=ax,
    layout='grid',
    vertex_color='steelblue',
    vertex_label=g.vs["name"], 
    autocurve=True,
    #vertex_label=range(g.vcount()),
    edge_label=g.es['label'],
    edge_width=g.es['width'],
    edge_curved="0.2",
    #edge_label=g.es["weight"],
    edge_color='#666',
    edge_align_label=False,
    edge_background='white'
)
```

Comment: **please**, no images of code! This is not reproducible...

Comment: Please help with this, I removed the code image and put in real code as advised

Answer (score 1):

python-igraph dev here.

`autocurve` is designed as a global option at present. Per-edge setting would be a little difficult to handle if there are several parallel edges between the same two nodes.

Of course, you could split the graph into two, one with the curved and one with the straight edges, and plot twice.

Comment: Maybe provide an example of how the double plotting code would look like given OP's example?

Comment: Thank you, at least it is not something that I am missing, it just can't be done. The graph I was trying to draw is as follow, it looks very much better with the mixture of curved and straight edges. Actually, I don't know how to add the picture of what I was going to show you.